# Как существенно повысить временную эффективность программы в ruby?

Tags: ruby, производительность

```
n = 1000000000  
s = 0  
i = 1  
while i <= n  
  s += i  
  i += 1  
end  
puts s
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Почитайте про арифметическую прогрессию, этому в 7 классе учат

Comment: Умножением. Об остальном нужно догадаться.

Answer (score 1):

Руби не знаю, но вообще так:

```
n = 1000000000  
s = n * (n + 1) / 2
puts s
```